# Error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token at line 6

Tags: c++, function, file-handling

I am trying to get the output of this function in a .txt file named Password.txt. The function to print was running easily separately but as I put it inside this program to get the output, this error is showing:

> Error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token at line 6

I tried removing void but not working.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void passn1()
{
   void print(char set[],string pre,int n,int k)
   {
       if(k==0)
       {
            cout<<pre<<endl;
            return;
       }
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
            string newp;
            newp=pre+set[i];
            print(set,newp,n,k-1);
       }
   }
   void printk(char set[],int k,int n)
   {
       print(set,"",n,k);
   }
   ptk()
   {
        char set1[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
        int k=6;
        printk(set1,k,10);
   }
}
int main()
{
    ofstream fo;
    fo.open("Password.txt",ios::out);
    fo<<passn1();
    fo<<endl;
    fo.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me by telling where am I going wrong.

Comment: "help me by telling where am I going wrong" - You are going wrong here: `void passn1()
{
   void print(...` - you cannot nest function declarations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to define a function inside the body of another function, which is not allowed, as the compiler error suggests.

Moreover, you cannot send to `std::ofstream` a function call (`fo<<passn1();`), it doesn't make sense, since the function's return type is `void` (it returns nothing).

Since you have a recursive function (`print()`), the easiest thing would be to take the output stream to the file (`std::ofstream`) as a parameter in your function, and write `pre` directly to it. Of course you'd need to carry this ofstream parameter along the function chain.

Putting everything together, you'd something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void print(char set[], string pre, int n, int k, ofstream& fo)
{
    if(k==0)
    {
        fo << pre << endl;
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        string newp;
        newp=pre+set[i];
        print(set, newp, n, k-1, fo);
    }
}

void printk(char set[],int k,int n, ofstream& fo)
{
    print(set, "", n, k, fo);
}

void ptk(ofstream& fo)
{
    char set1[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    int k=6;
    printk(set1, k, 10, fo);
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fo;
    fo.open("Password.txt",ios::out);
    ptk(fo);
    fo<<endl; // this will append an empty line at the end of the file
    fo.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Output (content of Password.txt):

```
000000
000001
// rest of the data here...
999998
999999
```

Comment: "you cannot send to std::ofstream a function call (fo<<passn1();), it doesn't make sense" - It would make sense if the function returned a `std::string` or some other type that has a suitable `operator<<` defined. But of course I agree that it doesn't make sense when the function in question returns `void`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl pardon me, I clarified, thanks for that!